# Objective-C application with bidirectional file transfer across internet

Tags: objective-c, p2p, file-transfer

Basically, I'm building a *Dropbox* clone that will avoid cloud storage. Ok, I'm not building it, but trying to estimate the amount of work needed.

Been reading different p2p options here on SO, but actually, there are very little topics on centralised p2p connections and how to build them from ground-up. I'm not even sure if it's appropriate to call it a *p2p* at all.

From ActionScript background I know that it can establish an UDP connection between 2 different clients across the globe with provided centralised server (RTMFP). It's highly abstracted, it doesn't even require to open ports and clients don't know the IPs of each other. So the subset of given options is quite limited.

Anyway, I need create a server-side app and a client-side app that will try to sync files between connected clients. I've read that socket connections are used for file transfers. And the questions here are:

- **How to pair the clients**?
- **What should server do**?
- **What should client do**?

Thank you.

**NB**

Establishing connections and file syncing solutions are out of the question.